# failed because this element is disabled

Tags: cypress

I have an error in cypress that I get sometimes but other times the tests pass.
I have tried everything but I need it to always work

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should dig deeper to understand why your test is flaky. You haven't specified where you are running this test so it could be your app issue or your resources being tied if you are running in CI.

Either way, it is always good to add assertions before invoking an action on the HTML element. This will ease out the debugging any failures/flakiness. Plus, these assertions will be relatively quick if your app is ready.

```js
// sometimes it is good to check a checkbox is disabled before you enable it
cy.get(x.foward_button1)
  .should('be.visible')
  .and('be.disabled')
cy.get(x.checkboxes)
  // good assertion for any element
  .should('be.visible')
  // good for any button, checkbox, radio, etc
  .and('be.enabled')
  .click({multiple:true})
cy.get(x.foward_button1)
  .should('be.visible')
  .and('be.enabled')
```

Answer (score 1):

Is button changing state from disabled to enabled by some conditions for exmaple validation or data request?
if yes before clicking button tell cypress to wait for these conditions to end. You can do it ugly way by telling cypress to wait for example 5secounds.

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait

```
cy.intercept('GET', '/exampleGet').as('someFetch')

cy.wait(5000) or cy.wait('@someFetch')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `force: true` to click the disabled button:

```js
cy.get('x.forward_button1').click({force: true})
```